# how to override private function in model in Magento-2

Tags: php, magento-2.1.7

How to override private function in model. If anyone knows please explain me

Comment: you can override model file using preference and update your function.

Comment: yes.i follow your instruction .But it only override public function in that class.I want to override private function.wt can i do

Comment: plz show your code for which file u want to override

Comment: <?php
namespace Maha\CreateLastname\Model\ResourceModel;
//use Magento\Customer\Model\Address as CustomerAddressModel;

    class AddressRepository extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository
    {
    protected function _validate(CustomerAddressModel $customerAddressModel)
    {
      
            echo "Model Rewrite Working"; die();

        }

    }
i can't override private fun in above code in my module

Comment: plz share it in your original post

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200687/how-to-override-private-function-in-model-magento-2   this is my post .it's not working.wt can i do

Comment: This is the exact same question. Please do not post questions twice. You should update your answer with new info and you can set a bounty to attract more (quality) answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Private functions cannot be overridden in a child class.**
You can easily override public functions.