# How to override private function in Model (Magento-2)

Tags: php, magento-2.1.7

My di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository" type="Maha\CreateLastname\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository" />
</config>
```

AddressRepository.php file(override model file)

```
<?php
    namespace Maha\CreateLastname\Model\ResourceModel; 
    class AddressRepository extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository
    { 
        private function _validate(CustomerAddressModel $customerAddressModel)  {
            echo "Model Rewrite Working";
            die();
        }
    }
```

I want override the private function in this code. What can I do? I want to change anything in my code

Answer (score 4):

**Private functions cannot overridden in child class.**

If you want to change the logic in `_validate` function you can use below method.

Override `save` function, inside that instead of calling `$this->_validate($addressModel)` function use your own custom function, like below

```
private function _validateCustom(CustomerAddressModel $customerAddressModel) {
//your custom validation logic
}
```

Change the `di.xml` into

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface" type="Maha\CreateLastname\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository" />
</config>
```

Because in the `AccountManagement.php` they injected `AddressRepositoryInterface` in `__constructor`.

> You can achieve this by using `plugin` as well and that is recommended way.

Comment: but it's not working.please explain code briefly

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest code which you tried

Comment: <?php

namespace Maha\CreateLastname\Plugin\Customer\Model\ResourceModel;
class AddressRepository
{
     public function save()
    {
         echo "save form";
    }
    private function _validate(CustomerAddressModel $customerAddressModel) {


        echo "hi";exit;
    }
}
?>

Comment: is the execution is going into `save` function??

Comment: if anything changes in my code .I want the execution is go to validate function.

Comment: Don't use validate function create a new function(validateCustom) and call that( validateCustom) function inside save function

Comment: namespace Maha\CreateLastname\Plugin\Customer\Model\ResourceModel;
class AddressRepository 
{
     public function save(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address)
    {
         $this->_validate($addressModel);
         echo "save form";exit;
    }
   private function _validateCustom(CustomerAddressModel $customerAddressModel) 
           {
        echo "Model";
    }
}..............But it's  does not working

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: it's throw ......Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to private method Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository::_validate()

Comment: remove the `_validate()` function from your class. Create a new function(`customValidate`) and copy `_validate` function code into `customValidate` function and change the logic. 

After that inside `save` function call `customValidate` function.

Comment: $this->customValidate($addressModel);this func in save method.it does not call private function customValidate(CustomerAddressModel $customerAddressModel)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68439/discussion-between-meenakshisundaram-r-and-mahalakshmi-m).

Comment: One more doubt,admin panel->allcustomer->edit->address....throw error last name is required field